# Do I have to write separate Bluetooth Low Energy code for Windows 8.1 and Windows 10?

Tags: c#, windows, bluetooth, windows-10, bluetooth-lowenergy

When developing an application that communicates with a Bluetooth Low Energy device on Windows, does one have to write separate code for Windows 8.1 and Windows 10?

I need to connect to a custom device that only has a Bluetooth Low Energy chip in it, the reason I think it would need a separate version is because the API might be different for Windows 10? That is the question, is it the same API?

Comment: Are you looking to use UWP?

Comment: @Av4t4r Not necessarily, using UWP is not a requirement. Would it work with UWP, or without UWP?

Comment: you're not really saying *what* you are going to do, or how could it possibly need a separate version for Windows 10....

Comment: @Av4t4r I need to connect to a custom device that only has a Bluetooth Low Energy chip in it, the reason I think it would need a separate version is because the API might be different for Windows 10? That is the question, is it the same API?

Comment: You should edit your question to reflect that. One way to do that is using (WinSocks)[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362928(v=vs.85).aspx]; the API shouldn't be too different in Win 10 vs Win 8

Comment: @Av4t4r Do you know, if using WinSocks is for Bluetooth Low Energy? My external device that I need to connect to is Bluetooth Low Energy only, which is a lot less common than the regular Bluetooth.

Comment: Do you really think that MS would change an API that worked in Win8 so radically that it wouldn't work at all in Win10? If you write your code to work on Win8, it should work on 10 just fine.